# Shifting characters within a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

```
String newStr;

public RandomCuriosity(String input){
    newStr = input;
}

public void shiftChars(){
    char[] oldChar = newStr.toCharArray();
    char[] newChar = new char[oldChar.length];
    newChar[0] = oldChar[oldChar.length-1];
    for(int i = 1; i < oldChar.length; i++){
        newChar[i] = oldChar[i-1];
    }
    newStr = String.valueOf(newChar);
}
```

I created a method that shifts characters forward by one. For example, the input could be:

The input: `Stackoverflow`

The output: `wStackoverflo`

How I did it is I mutated an instance of a string. Convert that string to a `char` array (calling it `oldChar`), assigned the last index of of `oldChar` as the first index of `newChar`, and made a for-loop that took the first index of `oldChar` as the second index of my new `Char` array and so forth. Lastly, I converted the char array back to a string.

I feel like I did way too much to do something *very* simple. Is there a more efficient way to do something like this?

EDIT Thanks for the great answers!

Comment: What's the time and space complexity of your program?

Comment: I have no clue, though I think it's pretty high.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it should be on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is the substring solution actually any faster? I don't know if substring yields O(1) or not? The newer versions of java don't hold an offset anymore if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Cruncher The `substring` uses the overloaded constructor that takes an offset and a count and uses `Arrays.copyOfRange()` to get a copy of the char array.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in that case, OP's solution should be the same complexity.

Comment: @Cruncher Let's analyze. OP's code: O(n) to copy the String to a new char array, O(n) to copy each value to a new array and O(n) to copy the char back to a `String`, for a total of O(3n). JB's code: O(1) to get the first char, O(n) to get the substring, O(n) in the String concatenation, and O(n) for the `StringBuilder`'s `toString()`. Unless I missed something, time-wise, they have the exact same complexity.

Comment: As a side note on terminology: You didn't mutate an instance of String. You created a new String with a similar but changed value. Strings are immutable.

Comment: Good catch. You're right on that. If strings were mutable I wouldn't have had to do all the things I did =)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
newStr = newStr.charAt(newStr.length() - 1) + newStr.substring(0, newStr.length() - 1);
```

Comment: Woah. That's an intense one-liner. So let me get this straight. You treated the last index as a char, and the chars before the last index as a complete string?

Comment: Yes. But you may also use `newStr.substring(newStr.length() - 1)` as the first operand if you find it clearer.

Comment: This is a very beautiful solution, and a great use of in-built Java methods. Thanks JB.

Comment: @JB Can you check my last comment to the question and comment on if I am right about the complexity?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: looks right to me. O(3n) is O(n) though. Anyway, unless the string is really huge, the performance of such a simple task should not be something you would try to optimize.

Comment: @JBNizet Out of curiosity, is there any thing inherently bad about my original code?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: there's nothing inherently bad, but it's longer and harder to understand than the one-liner that uses higher-level methods. The one-liner does exactly what you intend to do: create a string beginning with the last char and ending with the n-1 first chars. Without javadoc, your implementation requires a deeper analysis to understand what it does. Using frequently used library methods like substring also guarantees that the code will be jitted and benefit from any optimization that might be introduced in the JDK.

Comment: Just correcting code line. It is missing `()` in second `newStr.length`. Would be:

`newStr = newStr.charAt(newStr.length() - 1) + newStr.substring(0, newStr.length() - 1);`

Answer (score 1):

You can made your life simpler :

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    String input = "Stackoverflow";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        input = shift(input);
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}

public static String shift(String s) {
    return s.charAt(s.length()-1)+s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
}
```

Output :

```
wStackoverflo
owStackoverfl
lowStackoverf
flowStackover
rflowStackove
erflowStackov
verflowStacko
overflowStack
koverflowStac
ckoverflowSta
ackoverflowSt
tackoverflowS
Stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

```
char[] oldChar = newStr.toCharArray();
char[] newChar = new char[oldChar.length];
newChar[0] = oldChar[oldChar.length - 1];
System.arrayCopy(oldChar, 0, newChar, 1, oldChar.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilders.

```
StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
strb.append(oldChar[oldChar.length-1]).append(oldchar.substring(0, oldChar.length-1));
newStr = strb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
        String old = "String";
        char first = old.charAt(old.length()-1);
        String newString = first+old.substring(0,old.length()-1);
        System.out.println(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, but without using loops, for left and right shift:

```
public static String cyclicLeftShift(String s, int n){ //'n' is the number of characters to shift left
        n = n%s.length();
        return s.substring(n) + s.substring(0, n);
    }
      
public static String cyclicRightShift(String s, int n){ //'n' is the number of characters to shift right
        n = n%s.length();
        return  s.substring(s.length() - n , s.length()) + s.substring(0, s.length() - n);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

By Java, u can shift it to forward by O(n) where n is how many times to go forward by character which space o(1)

```
public static String shiftChars(String s , int times) {
    String temp = s;
    for (int i = 0; i < times ; i++) {
        temp =  temp.charAt(temp.length()-1)+temp.substring(0, temp.length()-1);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is the **same** as the accepted answer by JB Nizet.

Comment: not matter a lot. Actually, just I want to share how I used this code with my problem, thank you to get your attention on the code ^_^

Comment: Your Answer may be deleted though. The idea is to post different answers.